# RESideMenu Dependency injection

Tags: objective-c, dependency-injection

I used the RESideMenu story board example project download here https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu however I have no idea how I inject my managedObjectContext created in AppDelegate into the main view controllers e.g. HomeViewController displayed by RESideMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, my advice is to avoid problems and do not use storyboards if you want to use DI.

In case you want to use them, the view controllers are created by the storyboard hence constructor injection is not possible so I assume you are using setter injection.

A simple solution is to get the app delegate's context in the in your view controller's context getter like this:

```
// .h

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

// .m

- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
    if(_managedObjectContext == nil)
    {
        _managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Yes, this is not DI since the view controllers are looking for the context instead of asking for it but is not so bad and it still allows you inject a different context with ease in your tests.

Another solution would be to override `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` in your UIStoryboard subclass and inject the context there, but you would need some way to check if the requested view controller needs the context or not (you could use respondsToSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext)), and also you would need the context in your storyboard subclass (you could either inject it or access it like in the code above). Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998759/typhoon-assembly-and-storyboard-created-viewcontrollers) to see a similar approach but using [Typhoon](http://www.typhoonframework.org/).

Last thing to say is that injecting a context in a view controller is prone to end up having huge view controllers, I would inject the context in other model objects and then inject those in your view controllers.

Comment: Thanks for advice I thought the story boards seemed like a good way to get started with IOS development (first attempted at an app) but I see what you mean in terms of limitations in DI. I think I will go back and do it again without the story board.

When you say 'I would inject the context in other model objects and then inject those in your view controllers.' I guess the best thing would be to create a class that provided the basic queries/functions with the context for injection into the view controllers

Comment: About storyboards, is matter of taste, and in fact they have some pros, but yes when it comes to DI they make things a little bit more complicated. Anyway tools like typhoon may help you as you can see in that question. And you are right with the context stuff, it is better to have other class that deals with queries and other business logic keeping your view controllers thiner.